# How to calculate green area plus red area without using integral calculus?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I found this problem on the net, and the truth is I don't know where to start, someone would be so kind to explain it to me, I would be very grateful.
edited

[image]

Comment: For starters, they are similar triangles, as both of the leftmost angles are inscribed angles and subtend the same arc.

Comment: Find the area in terms of a,b? is R given?

Comment: It does not specify that, it says only sum of areas. I will edit the figure for better understanding (I will add letters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: AreaCalculation]

There is nothing wrong with the methodology used in kyary’s answer. However, it has generated a surprisingly long thread of comments, mostly exchanges of openions between the asker and the answerer. In view of that, we decided to post the following answer, which gives the complete solution to the problem at hand. We hope that our answer would help OP to clear doubts, if he or she still has some. Please note that certain elements of the method given below are somehow slightly different from that of kyary’s solution.

Let the radius of the circle be $r$. We denote the measure of angles $B\hat{O}A$ and $D\hat{O}C$ by $2\omega$ and $2\phi$ respectively. From this, it follows that
$$ \measuredangle BDA = \omega \quad\text{and}\quad \measuredangle DAC =\phi.$$

The external angle at the vertex $E$ of $\triangle AED$ is equal to $60^o$. Therefore,
$$\phi+\omega=60^o. \tag{1}$$

As shown in the $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$, we extend the given configuration by drawing the four radii $OA$, $OB$, $OC$, and $OD$ and the line segment $AD$. Addition of the radii gives us two isosceles triangles $BOA$ and $DOC$, using which we shall write,
$$a=2r\sin \left(\phi\right) \quad\text{and}\quad b=2r\sin \left(\omega\right).$$

When we remove $r$ from these two equations, we get
$$b sin \left(\phi\right) = a\sin \left(\omega\right).$$

Therefore, we have
$$ b sin \left(\phi\right) = a\sin \left(60^o - \phi\right) = \frac{a}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}\cos \left(\phi\right) -\sin \left(\phi\right)\right).$$

By simplifying this trigonometric identity as illustrated below, we can obtain a value for $\phi$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.
$$\phi = \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{a+2b}\right)$$

There exists a very similar expression for $\omega$ as well.
$$\omega = \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}b}{b+2a}\right)$$

Now, we are in a position to express the radius $r$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.
$$r=\frac{a}{2\sin \left(\phi\right)}=\frac{a}{2\sin \left[\tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{a+2b}\right)\right]} \tag{2}$$

By the way, we need an expression for $\left(\phi - \omega\right)$ as well. We assume that you are versed in manipulating inverse trigonometric functions.
$$\phi - \omega =  \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{a+2b}\right) - \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}b}{b+2a}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{a+2b}-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}b}{b+2a}}{1+ \dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{a+2b}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{3}b}{b+2a}}\right)$$

Upon simplifying, the above expression yields the following equation.
$$\phi - \omega = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\left(a^2 – b^2\right)}{ a^2 + b^2+4ab}\right) \tag{3}$$

Now, we can express the two areas $A_{a}$ and $A_{b}$.
$$A_{a}=r^2\phi – \frac{1}{2}r^2\sin \left(2\phi\right)$$
$$A_{b}=r^2\omega– \frac{1}{2}r^2\sin \left(2\omega\right)$$

$$\therefore\quad A_{a} + A_{b}=\left[\phi + \omega - \frac{1}{2}\Big(\sin \left(2\phi\right) + \sin \left(2\omega\right)\Big)\right]r^2$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad = \Big[\phi + \omega - \sin\left(\phi + \omega\right) \cos\left(\phi - \omega\right) \Big]r^2. \tag{4}$$

By substituting values from (1), (2), and (3) in (4), we obtain,
$$ A_{a} + A_{b} =\frac{2\pi-3\sqrt{3}\cos\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}\left(a^2 – b^2\right)}{ a^2 + b^2+4ab}\right) \right]}{24\sin^2\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{a+2b}\right)\right]}a^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Expanding-upon a comment ...

---

Taking $A$ and $B$ as endpoints of segments $b$ and $a$ as shown, define $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the inscribed angles angles at this points, subtending chords $a$ and $b$. Let the cross-chords meet at $P$, making an angle of $\theta$ there; the problem specifically has $\theta=60^\circ$, but I like to work in generalities whenever possible, to see how parameters contribute to the outcome. (Note that, by a cousin of the Inscribed Angle Theorem, we know that $\theta=\alpha+\beta$.) Let the circle have radius $r$.

[image]

Naming the "other" endpoint of chord $a$ as $P'$, we can find $A'$ so that $\triangle PAB\sim\triangle P'A'B$. As $\overline{P'A'}$ subtends an angle $\beta$, it must have length $b$.

Now, by the (Extended) Law of Sines and the Law of Cosines, we can find the length of $\overline{A'B}$ in two ways:

$$(2r\sin P')^2=|A'B|^2=a^2+b^2-2a b\cos P'
\quad\to\quad r^2=\frac{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\theta}{4\sin^2\theta}$$
Thus, radius $r$ is determined by $a$, $b$, and $\theta$.

Since the circular segment determined by the new $b$ chord matches that of the original, we can leverage *it* to calculate the target area. Re-focusing ...

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\text{target area} &= |\operatorname{sector}BP'A|-|\square OA'P'B| \\[6pt]
&=\frac12r^2\angle A'OP - |\triangle A'OP| - |\triangle A'P'B| \\[6pt]
&=r^2\theta - \frac12r^2\sin2\theta - \frac12ab\sin\theta \\[6pt]
&=r^2\theta - \frac12\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\theta}{4\sin^2\theta}\cdot 2\sin\theta\cos\theta + ab\sin\theta\right) \\[6pt]
&=r^2\theta - \frac1{4\sin\theta}\left((a^2+b^2)\cos\theta+2ab\cos^2\theta + 2ab\sin^2\theta\right) \\[6pt]
&=r^2\theta - \frac1{4\sin\theta}\left((a^2+b^2)\cos\theta+2ab\right)
\end{align}$$

Thus, the target area itself is expressed in terms of $a$, $b$, and $\theta$, as desired. $\square$

(Considering the final form of the quadrilateral area, I suspect there may be a cleaner path to it.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to the question involving [extended sine law](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ycbWy8C9) and circle angle properties.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: you don't need to find theta for this question, can use trig identities instead to get an exact answer

Comment: You can get to the formula for $r$ a bit more easily: let $A$ and $B$ be the be the respective vertices of your $60^\circ-\theta$ and $\theta$ angles, and let $P$ be the vertex of the $120^\circ$ angle (ie, where the original chords cross). Taking $P'$ to be the other endpoint of $a$, let $A'$ be the point such that $\triangle ABP\sim\triangle A'BP'$. Since $A'P'$ subtends angle $\theta$, it has length $b$. By the Laws of Sines and Cosines, $$(2r\sin P')^2=|A'B|^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos P'$$ where we know $P'=120^\circ$.

Comment: @kyary,thank ; As I understand you applied the sine law, I was lost when you solved that equation with constants.
Then apparently you don't need it, then by the same law you put an expression for R, but will you use that one?
I understand that the dashed part is the area of the sector minus the area of the isosceles triangle, but the height is in terms of R (I applied Pythagoras and it is a pretty ugly expression. (my English is not very good) 
Could you clarify what you did (as I see it, you started doing something and then you realized that there were unnecessary things) am I right

Comment: @Blue, thanks , I will check your idea later

Comment: @Blue I am impaired (extreme migraines), so I can't use the screen a lot

Comment: @BeTDa  Let me clarify the structure of the solution

Comment: @BeTDa The overlying goal was to find theta and R to get the answer, agree?

Comment: @BeTDa I used EXTENDED sine law (not regular sine law) to get an equation with only theta to solve for it. Do you see where the first equation comes from?

Comment: @BeTDa Then we do a few manipulations to solve for sin of theta. Do you see how this is done? I obfuscated needless details by having (constant) instead of writing out the constant factor.

Comment: @BeTDa Once we have sin of theta, I got the radius of the circle through another application of EXTENDED sine law

Comment: @BeTDa  Thus, having found R and sin of theta, we are able to use these two values along with b to find the area of the shaded region. This part is standard 10th grade math, so I didn't include it.

Comment: @Blue I am fine with my answer being deleted if there's another more well formatted one posted. Otherwise deletions would counterproductive.

Comment: @kyary,one doubt, I will try to follow your reasoning, according to the problem the area as a function of ay b, without theta has a certain value ?that part of the calculation I do not see it well

Comment: @BeTDa I do not understand what you're asking. What part of the calculation are you referring to and what confuses you about it?

Comment: @ kyary, his should be very simple but today I am short sighted, you say that each area is determined by theta ,R,a and thetha ,R,b
I just want to know what is the final value of theta and R !!!(for me to arrive to those values from what you did)
(if you can send another explanation I would appreciate it.)

Comment: @Blue,Would you be so kind to put a figure with what you indicate, I get lost with the A'and P'. A figure would help a lot to the understanding of what you tell me.

Comment: Many thanks to all those who participated in the writing and solution of this problem and above all, thanks for the time invested.